# Create a georeferenced PDF using a shapefile and add informations in R

Tags: r, geoprocessing, rgdal, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

I created a georeferenced PDF using a shapefile and OK no problem, but I'd like to know if is possible to insert a title inside a pdf (in top position "My geo PDF"), points of interest (`pts.sampling`) and values too.

In my example:

## Packages

```
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)
```

## Create 2 polygons

```
sr <- SpatialPolygons(list(
Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 181477, 181294, 181007, 180409,
  180162, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 333250, 333558, 333676,
  332618, 332413, 332349)))),'1'),
Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437,
  179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 330889, 330683,
  331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373)))),'2')))
```

## Convert in spatial polygon

```
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sr, data.frame(row.names=c('1','2'), PIDS=1:2))
srdf@data
proj4string(srdf) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

## Create shapefile

```
writeOGR(srdf, getwd(), 'ARS', 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

## Read shapefile

```
contorno_line<- readShapeLines ("ARS.shp")
```

## Plot

```
plot(contorno_line, main="My geo PDF")
```

## Points of interest and values

```
x<-c(180684.2,  179786.2,   180766.4,   180335.5,   181392.6,   180881.9,   181167.9,   180544.5,   180680.9,   180259.6)
y<-c(332264.8,  331057.3,   332190.5,   331643.7,   333384.4,   333444.8,   333381.6,   332607.9,   332625.9,   331867.7)
Class<-c(5,5,3,1,2,3,5,5,2,2)
pts<-cbind(x,y,Class)
pts.sampling = SpatialPoints(pts, proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
points(pts.sampling, col="red")
text(pts.sampling,labels=paste(pts.sampling$Class), cex= 0.7,pos=3)
```

### Create a geoPDF

```
writeOGR(contorno_line, dsn = "mygeoPDF", layer = "contorno_geo", driver = "PDF")
```

But my problem is, how I can put `main="My geo PDF"`, `points(pts.sampling, col="red")` and `text(pts.sampling,labels=paste(pts.sampling$Class), cex= 0.7,pos=3)` inside mygeoPDF.pdf created?

Comment: Have you seen this? Might be useful. Looks like you might be better off plotting the shapefile in R, adding the title in the plot window and then exporting it as an image/PDF, if you don't want to write it back as a shapefile. Might be easier that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615298/is-there-something-similar-to-pdf-dev-off-for-shapefiles-using-r